# Exception in plugin Android Support, Worker exited due to exception

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-2.2

I just updated to Android Studio 2.2.2 (stable) on Linux and now I get constant crashes.

Already tried:

- Invalidate Caches / Restart
- Clean Project
- Removing gradle cache: `rm .gradle/caches/* -rf`
- Removing Android Studio config directory: `.AndroidStudio2.2`

```
Worker exited due to exception: Method getName in class org/jetbrains/android/dom/resources/ResourceElement has illegal modifiers: 0x411
java.lang.ClassFormatError: Method getName in class org/jetbrains/android/dom/resources/ResourceElement has illegal modifiers: 0x411
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:760)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:642)
    at com.intellij.util.lang.UrlClassLoader._defineClass(UrlClassLoader.java:261)
    at com.intellij.util.lang.UrlClassLoader.defineClass(UrlClassLoader.java:257)
    at com.intellij.util.lang.UrlClassLoader._findClass(UrlClassLoader.java:226)
    at com.intellij.ide.plugins.cl.PluginClassLoader.loadClassInsideSelf(PluginClassLoader.java:119)
    at com.intellij.ide.plugins.cl.PluginClassLoader.tryLoadingClass(PluginClassLoader.java:73)
    at com.intellij.ide.plugins.cl.PluginClassLoader.loadClass(PluginClassLoader.java:62)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at com.android.tools.idea.editors.strings.StringResourceEditorProvider.canViewTranslations(StringResourceEditorProvider.java:38)
    at com.android.tools.idea.editors.strings.StringResourceEditorNotificationProvider.createNotificationPanel(StringResourceEditorNotificationProvider.java:51)
    at com.android.tools.idea.editors.strings.StringResourceEditorNotificationProvider.createNotificationPanel(StringResourceEditorNotificationProvider.java:32)
    at com.intellij.ui.EditorNotificationsImpl$4.performInReadAction(EditorNotificationsImpl.java:146)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.util.ReadTask$1.compute(ReadTask.java:70)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.util.ReadTask$1.compute(ReadTask.java:67)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runReadAction(ApplicationImpl.java:966)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.util.ReadTask.runBackgroundProcess(ReadTask.java:67)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.util.ProgressIndicatorUtils$7.compute(ProgressIndicatorUtils.java:227)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.util.ProgressIndicatorUtils$7.compute(ProgressIndicatorUtils.java:223)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$3.run(CoreProgressManager.java:162)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$2.run(CoreProgressManager.java:142)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.registerIndicatorAndRun(CoreProgressManager.java:446)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:392)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:54)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.runProcess(CoreProgressManager.java:127)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.runProcess(CoreProgressManager.java:159)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.util.ProgressIndicatorUtils.runUnderProgress(ProgressIndicatorUtils.java:223)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.util.ProgressIndicatorUtils.access$000(ProgressIndicatorUtils.java:45)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.util.ProgressIndicatorUtils$6$2.run(ProgressIndicatorUtils.java:188)
    at com.intellij.util.concurrency.BoundedTaskExecutor$2.run(BoundedTaskExecutor.java:187)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Answer (score 0):

To resolve this I removed the Android Studio config directory: `.AndroidStudio2.2`
Deleted the Android Studio installation: `android-studio`
Downloaded version 2.2.1 and updated from the clean install.