# Disable Multi-Window Support in Android

Tags: android

I'm trying to disable multi window support using  `android:resizeableActivity="false"` inside application tag in the manifest file. But it shows this warning -
`Attribute resizeableActivity is only used in API level 24 and higher (current min is 15)`

Then I used "*suppress with tool:TargetApi Attribute*". This gave me `RuntimeException: Worker exited due to exception:`

What should I do now ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/40168257/6271729 look at this and http://stackoverflow.com/a/40168257/6271729 this both.

Comment: @Niharika already i have checked that two questions. It is different.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
Attribute resizeableActivity is only used in API level 24 and higher (current min is 15)
```

You can safely ignore that warning because [Multi Window Support](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/multi-window.html) is only available from Android 7.0(API level 24) and above. On lower versions this line `android:resizeableActivity="false"` will simply be ignored.